# C++ : how do I convert a char array into a buffer for general types T

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, buffer

My assignment is to make a buffer in a template for general types T. I'm given an allocated array of chars and I'm supposed to turn that into a buffer without using STL.

I'm still new to some of this and I can't figure out how to get that memory and turn it into an array of T's (knowing how much space a type T takes up). I've tried messing around with addresses but that doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To convert between raw memory and objects, you need to *construct* objects, which you do with the `new` operator, in its *placement* form. This is generally not something you should ever do unless you're writing a dedicated container class, but here's how:

```
char memory[sizeof(T) * 10];           // gives pointers to raw memory
T * objects[10];                       // stores pointers to objects

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    objects[i] = new (memory + i * sizeof(T)) T;      // even better: "::new"
}
```

Then to delete:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    objects[i]->~T();
}
```

This is still horribly wrong and bad in all kinds of ways, but it's a start.

Don't do this.

(Two things which are wrong with this: a) you need to guarantee appropriate alignment of the memory. b) you need to consider what happens if any of the constructors for `T` throw an exception.)